# Springboot JPA classes inheritance problem

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 classes: person and employee.
Employee derives from person. Person is not abstract and might be a ligate entity.
`Person table: id (PK), first_name, last_name`
`Employee table: employee_id (PK), person_id (FK), work_start_date`
The classes look like this:
`Person class:`

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "persons")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

`Employee class:`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "person_id")
public class Employee extends Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long employeeId;

    @Column(name = "start_work_date")
    private Date startDate;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Long getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(Long employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
}
```

And my repositroy:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
}
```

When I call the get of employees the employee members itself are filled but all my super class (Person) members are null...
Do I have to add to employee class a FK member to person?

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer inheritance over composition (with [`@OneToOne`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) relation between `Employee` and `Person`)?

Comment: As i read it, using the  InheritanceType.JOINED strategy the Employee must not have it's own id, since the comon id with Person is the join criteria

Comment: But in the organization you have your id and your worker number... And composition is possible but in object oriented there is a sense for employee to person inheritance relation.

Comment: One to one makes no sense. Inheritance is correct but remove the id from the sub class.

Comment: Is it possible to keep employee id as a pk in the db table or should it get removed as well?

Comment: Makes sense to leave it.